# ARKit 2 : Place 3D objects using ARKit causes screen to freeze in Xcode 10.1 and iOS 12

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, arkit, arscnview

I am placing virtual objects in real environments using ARKit. It is worked fine in Xcode 9 and iOS 11. But when i have updated Xcode and iOS, if I place virtual objects in detected plane it is getting freeze and if I rotate camera, camera also continuously braking. I am getting following log in Xcode

> `World tracking performance is being affected by resource constraints
>   1`

Guide me to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Only allow Portrait Device Orientation. It resolved this error for me.